# Shared logic between constructor and another function in Java Script

Tags: javascript

I have a situation like that:

```
class TestClass {
   constructor() {
    shared logic
  }

  anotherFunction() {
    shared logic
  }
}
```

How can I achieve that not duplicating the code?

Comment: Huh... put the logic within `anotherFunction` and call it from the constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As always, create a function for the shared logic, either inside of the class or outside of it.

```js
class TestClass {
    constructor() {
        this.sharedLogicFunction();
    }

    anotherFunction() {
        this.sharedLogicFunction();
    }

    sharedLogicFunction() {}
}
```

Comment: This looks exactly right! Note that the ONLY restriction here is that `super` must be called before `this` is referenced. If for some weird reason `sharedLogicFunction` needs to occur before a call to `super`, `sharedLogicFunction` would need to be made static or defined outside the class altogether.

Comment: But isn't it like that super needs to be called in order to access parent class, ie. when child class extends parent? Then we would have access to parents methods. In the scenario above is it really necassacy to call super in order to use 'this'?

Answer (score 0):

Put your code to the `anotherFunction()` and call this function from constructor.

```
class TestClass {
   constructor() {
    this.anotherFunction();
  }

  anotherFunction() {
    here is some logic to do
  }
}
```